# Numpy reshape array of arrays to 1D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

How do I get x to become a 1D array?
I found it convenient to create x like this,

```
x=np.array([[0,-1,0]*12,[-1,0,0]*4])
print x
print len(x)
```

returns

```
array([ [0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0],
       [-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0]], dtype=object)

2
```

I also tried making it like this, but the length is still 2

```
y=((0,1,0)*12,(-1,0,0)*4)
print y
```

returns

```
((0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), (-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0))
```

I have tried using numpy.reshape (on both x and y):

```
np.reshape(x,48)
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

Is it possible to reshape x or y when I have declared them like I did?

Comment: Your `x` is 2 lists of different length, 36 and 12.  Do you want one of length 48?

Comment: yes, actually the first answer does this nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the array, concatenate the lists with `+` instead of packing them in another list:

```
x = np.array([0,-1,0]*12 + [-1,0,0]*4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to make a 1D numpy array that has a length of 48. Try,

```
    import numpy as np
    x=np.array([[0,-1,0]*12])
    x= np.append(x,[-1,0,0]*4)
    print (x)
    print (len(x))
```

This yields,

```
[ 0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0
 -1  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0]
48
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually have a longer array that has more of those groups of 12 so I wanted to create it in a single line like with the + method above.